# filter object_list in django template

Tags: django, django-queryset

I create a template with object_list table 
I need filter by sub string then when the user will filter the table will updates online.

### its not work. what the right way to do this?

1. I create view for this filter get the ajax request with substring value

def filters_points(request):

```
point_list = Point.objects.all()

try:

    req = request.GET.get("filterData")
    if req:
        point_list = Point.objects.filter(onsitePointName__icontains=req)

except AttributeError:
    print("failed")

#qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', point_list)
#return HttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='application/json')

return render_to_response('point/point_list_update.html', {'point_list': point_list})
```

2. in HTML templete:

   {% for point in point_list   %}
   ...
    {{ point.mangoId }} 
    {{ point.onsitePointName }}  
   ....

Comment: Can you please add your error log and post your code in clean way

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your question isn't clear: what error are your seeing? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

built the input type for filter in django form:
 filterBySubstring = forms.CharField(label='substring', max_length=100, required=True)

and then get this value in the python code by:
form = PointForm(request.POST)

```
if request.method == 'POST':  
    filter_value = form['filterBySubstring'].value()
```

Answer (score 0):

option1:
you can use Custom template filter and tags from django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

```
 from django import template

 register = template.Library()

 @register.assignment_tag
 def get_filtered_points(qs, **kwargs):
   return qs.filter(**kwargs)
```

template:
         `{% get_filtered_points your_filter_query as new_point_list %}
          {% for book in new_point_list %}
            ...
          {% endfor %}`

> Note: Don't forget to load template tags in your template.

option 2: you can also use `intercularjs` for this as explained [here](http://intercoolerjs.org/examples/activesearch.html)